# Laravel Retrieving Translation Strings with Slash Returning the Slash with Backslash

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

What I try:

```
// SomeRequest.php
public function attributes()
{
    return [
        'phone' => __('Phone Number'),
    ];
}


// id.json
{
    "Phone Number": "No. Telp / HP"
}
```

What I expect when I retrieve the id language:
`No. Telp / HP`

What I get: `No. Telp \/ HP`

Can I retrieve it without additional backslash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you return data as a response in Laravel, it automatically encoded to json.

so when your return `No. Telp / HP`  it will be encoded to `No. Telp \/ HP`

usally, when you get resonose by you request, you decoded to get the result.

```
$v=json_encode("No. Telp / HP"); // $v will have "No. Telp \/ HP"

$v2 = json_decode($v); // $v2 will have No. Telp / HP
```